# Using Elasticquent with Docker in Laravel throwing "Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException "

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I am working on a Laravel project. I am now trying to integrate ElasticSearch with my Laravel application. I am using this package, https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent. I am adding an index for a model as follow.

```
$restaurant->addToIndex();
```

But, when I run the code, I got the following error.

```
   Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException 

  No alive nodes found in your cluster

  at vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php:53
    49|                 return $connection;
    50|             }
    51|         }
    52| 
  > 53|         throw new NoNodesAvailableException("No alive nodes found in your cluster");
    54|     }
    55| 
    56|     public function scheduleCheck()
    57|     {

      +12 vendor frames
```

My elastic search instance is in the docker-compose file.

```
elasticsearch:
    container_name: myan_es
    image: elasticsearch:6.5.1
    volumes:
      - es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - myan-network
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
```

I ping the localhost:9200 using curl. It is alive.

But it just does not work. What is missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try accessing localhost:9200 In the browser, you should see default elastic search response.

Comment: Hi. Yes I can see it.

Comment: How did you define elastic connect in Laravel?

Comment: It is not mentioned in the doc either. I dumped the package and trying another one.

Comment: The other packages are throwing the same error too.

Comment: Try this : https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-elasticsearch/amp/